# Why is a plastic bag transparent in infrared light?

Tags: optics, spectroscopy

This is a classic trick to do with a IR camera:
[image]

Bu why is the plastic bag transparent, while the glasses aren't? I've also heard that water is not transparent in IR light. What causes this phenomena?

Comment: check also this [related question](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/130459/why-are-objects-opaque/130681#130681)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

the physical reason why this is happening is that [absorption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absorption_%28electromagnetic_radiation%29) of a medium is frequency dependent.

### Mathematical description

The most prominent example of a natural description might be the [Lambert-Beer law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beer%E2%80%93Lambert_law) that states that the change of a quantity $q$, $dq/dx$ is related to its value at $x$ multiplied by a scalar factor $\lambda$, which might depend on some further parameters like the frequency $\nu$,
$$\frac{dq}{dx} = -\lambda(\nu) q$$

which has the solution
$$q(x) = q_0 e^{-\lambda(\nu) x}\, .$$

For our scenario, $x$ might be the distance a light ray already traveled into the plastic bag, $x\in[0,D_{bag}]$. In optics, one often uses the [extinction coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extinction_coefficient) $n''(\nu)$, the imaginary part of the index of refraction or the absorbance $A_\lambda$ giving the same information for $\Delta x=\lambda$ (to clearify: $\lambda$ here is the wavelength, not the parameter above).

### Electromagnetic case - penetration depth

Let us look directly at electrodynamics and how the Lambert-Beer law can be applied here.

We know that the absolute of the [wave vector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_vector) in a medium described by the (frequency dependent) refractive index $n(\omega) = n'(\omega) + \mathrm{i}n''(\omega)$ is given by $$k = \sqrt{n'(\omega) + \mathrm{i}n''(\omega)}\frac{\omega}{c}\, .$$

If now $n'  \gg n'' $ (which is true far away for resonances), we can expand it as
$$k = \sqrt{n'}\left(1 + \frac{\mathrm{i}}{2} \frac{n''}{n'} +\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{n''}{n'}\right)^2 \right)\frac{\omega}{c}\, .$$

Then, for a field $$\mathbf{E} \sim \mathbf{E_0} e^{\mathrm{i}{\mathbf{k\cdot r}-\omega t}}$$

we find that $$\frac{|\mathbf{E}|}{|\mathbf{E_0}|} \leq \frac{1}{e}$$

after a **penetration depth** of
$$d_p \approx 2 \frac{\sqrt{n'}}{n''}\frac{c}{\omega}\, .$$

This quantity can be seen as a **characteristic propagation length**.

### Light absorption of a plastic bag

Since plastic bags are often made of [polyethylene](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyethylene), we have to search for the **spectral properties** of it in the visible and infrared range to be able to **answer the question**. A quick search revealed that in [Optical Properties of Polyethylene: Measurement and Applications](http://www.jstor.org/stable/3575254?seq=4) on page four $n''(\nu)$ is given depending on the frequency in terms of [eV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronvolt) (visible light ranges roughly in 1.5 - 3 eV, IR is energetically lower).

With an $n''\leq 10^{-5}$ as may be interpreted from the figure given in the paper, we can calculate
$$d_p \approx 6\mathrm{cm}$$

if I did not miscalculate totally. So, we have to state that polyethylene cannot be accounted for the absorption alone as stated by [gigacyan](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/701/gigacyan) and [Georg](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/1370/georg) - **other absorbing effects** need to be considered (*In the given case we can only speculate that it maybe was doping with carbon which causes the bag to appear black*). These effects will result in a change of $n(\omega)$ including its imaginary part, hence resulting in a **changed penetration depth**.

But this discussion is **beyond the scope** of this answer - one would have to calculate the [electronic band structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_band_structure) of the material which is not an easy task of [solid-state physics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid-state_physics).

Nevertheless, I hope my explanations are sufficient to explain *makroskopic* absorption phenomena including the one considered here.

Sincerely

Robert

Comment: Polyethylene does not absorb _any_ visible light (10 eV is very far in the UV range).

Comment: @gigacyan: Thank you for your hint. Would you be so kind to give another material plastic bags relate to, I only found that polyethylene is the major ingredient. I may be safe to assume that my argumentation can be applied to this material as well.

Comment: Those 10 eV is well "down" in Vakuum-UV, where all organic material starts to be ionized. For that reason this cannot be called "resonance". The slope down at much shorten wavelenghts is the onset of "Roentgen" domain.

Comment: @Robert: most synthetic polymers are inherently white. As Georg pointed out, it is carbon powder that is added to make it black. Here it gets tricky because carbon conducts electricity and should absorb IR as well as visible.

Comment: @Georg: Thank you for your explanation of the curve. I might add some further explanations as well.

Comment: @gigacyan, carbon black should look like a "bad" metal = graphite , the difference is particle size. The smallest blacks go down to hundred atoms, so such a particle is surface only, nor real "interior". Like IR photography goes through mist, the IR passes the carbon black due to ratio of particle size to wavelength.

Comment: @gigacyan, "most synthetic polymers are inherently white" in a topic like this one, such an expression is not acceptable. "colorless" or better "tranparent"! A white plastic sheet is black in "see through" mode.

Comment: @ Robert Filter. Your reasoning (especially that following "Further Considerations...") is the same for any transparent clear substance. So it does not contain some information on PE. The reasons for absorption bands being somewhere and not at some other wavelength, are manyfold.

Comment: @Georg: I will erase the ansatz using polyethylene... Nevertheless we should be clear that we are talking from different perspectives. You want to describe the absorption process on a microscopic scale which is absolutely fine whereas I contain all these processes into $n''$ - the ansatz via Lambert-Beer is perfectly fine which I think we can agree on. Greets

Comment: @Georg: Ok, done :) I hope it is clear from it now that we cannot see the absorption from the spectral properties of polyethylene alone. Greets

Comment: Well done! :=) Georg

Comment: The first equation is wrong. k = (n' + in'')*w/c, There is no square root. For |E|/|E0| = 1/e then the penetration depth is d = c/(w*n''). But for |E|^2/|E0|^2 = 1/e indicating the depth where power or energy is reduced to 1/e then d = c/(2*w*n''). |E|/|E0| = 1/e is the relative amplitude. So there are some corrections to be made.... See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penetration_depth

Answer (score 1):

I am not a specialist in thermal vision so I will just answer your last question: **what causes these phenomena?**

Electromagnetic radiation (e.g. visible light) propagates through matter by polarizing it. Oscillating electromagnetic field polarizes molecule that, in turn, begins to emit electromagnetic radiation, and this cycle continues until the light comes from the other side.

Except, often it doesn't. If the frequency of the field is close to a resonant frequency of the molecule, the photon can be absorbed and its energy will be converted to heat. These resonances can be of different nature: absorption in the visible range is caused by electrons whereas nuclear motion is resonant with lower frequencies in the IR range. These resonances are individual and can be used for identifying molecules by measuring light absorption versus wavelength (it's called [Spectrophotometry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectrophotometry)).

**Update:** In case of conductors like metals or, in this case, black carbon, free electrons are resonant to any frequency and these materials can observe light of any wavelength. However, as Georg pointed out, particles of carbon black are much smaller than the wavelength of thermal IR (10 $\mu$m) and this could be the reason of small absorption efficiency.